# Webform submission values with PHP

Tags: 7, webforms

I am using webform 2 pdf module, where I am trying to set up a custom content to the pdf file.

I would like to acces the webform submission data, but I have no idea how to do it. Basically I would like to access them and use them as tokens.

I am on a basic level with both drupal and php, which means I have limits.

```
//simple first section    
<h1 align="center" style="font-family:verdana;" style="font-size:14;"><b>Registration<b></h1><br>

<p style="text-align:left; font-family:verdana; font-size:12;" ><b>1. Registered Data:</b></p>
<p style="text-align:left; font-family:verdana; font-weight: normal; font-size:12;" >[submission:values:personal_info:key]</p>

<p style="text-align:left; font-family:verdana; font-size:12;" ><b>2.  Declaration:</b></p>
// there comes the non-working php part
<p><?php 
    $var=($fields["institutuonal info"]);
    if ($var == "spec_inst") {
      echo "some juristic stuff";
    }
    ?></p>
```

So I am trying to export webform submission results to PDF, but the result depends on the submission content.

Comment: So, you are trying to export webform submission results to PDF?

Comment: Yes, but the result depends on the submission content.

Comment: Can you edit the question and elaborate on the dependency part?

Comment: Of course, I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I partly was able to access webform values. I still have a problem, that I cannot access to one single submission, altough I tried `$sid = GET[sid]` method. So here is my partly good code:

```
    //simple first section    
<h1 align="center" style="font-family:verdana;" style="font-size:14;"><b>Registration<b></h1><br>

<p style="text-align:left; font-family:verdana; font-size:12;" ><b>1. Registered Data:</b></p>
<p style="text-align:left; font-family:verdana; font-weight: normal; font-size:12;" >[submission:values:personal_info:key]</p>

<p style="text-align:left; font-family:verdana; font-size:12;" ><b>2.  Declaration:</b></p>


<?php
$submissions = webform_get_submissions(array('nid'=>1));
foreach ($submissions as $submission){
foreach ($submission->data as $row=>$data){
        if ($row == 4){
              if (in_array("0", $data)) {
                    print("long boring text content");
}}}}
?>
```

So still not what I wanted but that is another question.